# Need help automating TLS Cert Handling in Go

Tags: go, ssl, certificate, webserver

I have a simple Go webserver and I want it to use TLS certificates. I know certbot, the python application, and used it frequently so far, but I would like to pretty much automate everything. That's where I stumbled upon https://github.com/caddyserver/certmagic, which is pretty awesome. However, I cannot seem to wrap my head around using it in conjunction with a custom server struct.

```
srv := http.Server{
    ReadTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 2 * time.Second,
    IdleTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    ReadHeaderTimeout: 2 * time.Second,
    Handler: router,
    Addr: serverAddr,
}

if fileExists(serverCertFile) && fileExists(serverKeyFile) {
    if err := srv.ListenAndServeTLS(serverCertFile, serverKeyFile); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        panic("Couldn't start server with TLS")
    }
} else {
    if err := srv.ListenAndServe(); err != nil && err != http.ErrServerClosed {
        panic("Couldn't start server")
    }
}
```

This is the way I approached the problem so far, just using manually requested certificates. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs [here](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/caddyserver/certmagic?tab=doc#HTTPS) suggest to use `Listen()` instead of `HTTPS()` to make use of your own `http.Server` values.

```
listener, err := certmagic.Listen([]string{"yourdomain.com"})

srv := http.Server{
    ReadTimeout: 1 * time.Second,
    WriteTimeout: 2 * time.Second,
    IdleTimeout: 10 * time.Second,
    ReadHeaderTimeout: 2 * time.Second,
    Handler: router,
    Addr: serverAddr,
}

srv.Serve(listener)
```

Document for `Listent()`

> Listen manages certificates for domainName and returns a TLS listener. It uses the Default config.
> Because this convenience function returns only a TLS-enabled listener and does not presume HTTP is also being served, the HTTP challenge will be disabled. The package variable Default is modified so that the HTTP challenge is disabled.
> Calling this function signifies your acceptance to the CA's Subscriber Agreement and/or Terms of Service.

Comment: Ah, the I saw it was that Listen is a low-level TCP-Listener, not really an HTTP Listener. Will try that. I didn't know about the srv.Serve() function.

Comment: Do you know a way to use a arbitrary port instead of 443?

Comment: Looks like we cannot change the port according to this link https://github.com/caddyserver/certmagic/blob/5ed364019bb7bad1b8ccef4398f584c94923497c/certmagic.go#L452